# Excel formua like SUMIFs with criteria in different tables

Tags: excel

I don't know if I am missing something obvious or what, but I cannot wrap my brain around what I need from this.  I have a table with products available for sale and various criteria.  I have a second table with a smaller list of stores and a second column of whether I should include them in my results set.  In this example, I would never include store 789, but I might include 123 and/or 456, depending on whether an "x" was placed in that second column.

So, for my results, I would break them out by Product and color with a simple `SUMIFS` statement.  However, I really want to be able to filter the sites out if they are "x" on that second tab.  Any thoughts on how I could easily do that?  I did insert a column on my raw data sheet and just added an if statement, then I used that as a 4th criteria in my `SUMIFS`, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

I can get either matching stores or the rest of the filters, but I cannot figure how to make both work together in the same statement or how to include them if they are "x"-ed.

This will get me the filtered stores

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF('Tab1'!A:A,'Tab2'!A:A,'Tab1'!D:D))
```

Either of these will get me the filtered products:

```
=SUMIFS('Tab1'!D:D, 'Tab1'!B:B, A2, 'Tab1'!C:C, B2)
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Tab1'!B:B=A2), --('Tab1'!C:C=B2), 'Tab1'!D:D)
```

Tab1

```
Store | Product | Color | Sales
--------------------------------
 123  |  A      | Red  |   1
 123  |  A      | Blue |   2
 123  |  B      | Red  |   4
 456  |  A      | Blue |   8
 456  |  B      | Red  |   16
 789  |  A      | Red  |   32
 789  |  B      | Red  |   64
```

Tab2

```
Store | Include
---------------
 123  |       
 456  |  x
```

Results:

```
Product | Color | Sales
------------------------
  A     | Red   |   0
  A     | Blue  |   8
  B     | Red   |   16
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `VLookUp`'s to add the column from `Tab2` to `Tab1`?

For example, new Column `E`, to the right of `Sales`:

```
=VLookUp(A1, "Tab2", 2, False)
```

...and fill-down?

You could base `SumIf` criteria on multiple tables but personally I'd just keep the data together (dynamically) just to make it easier and neater.

Comment: Thanks.  I did do something similar to that, but I used Index/Match, as I wanted to know if it was missing from the list, too.  However, I was really hoping to keep that StoreList separate, because there are actually several data sheets that will need sums.

Answer (score 0):

Build a pivot table and use slicers to include or exclude specific data. Then you don't need a helper table and you don't need formulas, either. Just a few clicks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't ever used slicers, so I think I will try it out and see what I can find.